# Get difference using Flux

Tags: influxdb, flux

I have a simple counter which is stored in a InfluxDB. Now I would like to get the difference in the counter value between two points in time. So the result should only be a single value.

I tried the following query:

```
from(bucket: "influxdb")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "mqtt_consumer")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["host"] == "telegraf-1-18-1")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["topic"] == "shellies/shellyplug-s-DDE23E/relay/0/energy")
  |> difference()
```

But this does not give the difference between the two counter values (actually I have no idea what the result is supposed to be).

Can anyone give me a hint on how to use difference correctly?

Comment: Can you paste in a few lines of your sample data before and after you run your query - it may be that difference() isn't acting on the value you think it is.

Comment: Probably [this question](https://community.influxdata.com/t/difference-between-2-values-in-a-query/27922/12) is similar to yours and may help you.